# R: regular expression for date extraction

Tags: r, regex, date

I'm trying to extract date pattern from txt file using R.
I figured I could use str_extract and regular expression, but can't quite get the regex that would give me the intended result.

The pattern is likes of

January 21, 2016

March 3, 2019

April 15, 2013

and so on.

The current setup I have is that I loaded text file into R and put it as string variable called mystring, then

```
    pattern <- "January|February|March|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}"
    
    str_extract_all(mystring,pattern)
```

I think I'm on the right track, but can't quite get it work.
Eventually I also want to convert what I extracted and change character data to dates, in a default "2019-03-01" format, but I first need to figure out how to extract the data.

Comment: What does `str_extract_all(mystring,pattern)` return? Can you provide an example of `mystring` ?

Comment: It's quite lengthy, so I'll just post portion of it. Overall, looks like it's capturing all the month names appeared in txt file instead of set pattern like "January 21, 2016".                      [1] "February" "February" "May"      "May"      "May"      "November" "May"      "June"     "February"
[10] "January"  "May"      "October"  "May"      "May"      "May"      "May"      "May"      "May"     
[19] "March"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `lubridate`'s `mdy()` function, which will convert the string into a date which you can parse as you wish?

```
mdy("January 21, 2016")

[1] "2016-01-21"
```

Here's an example with multiple random dates:

```
random_dates <- format(sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 12), "%B %d, %Y")

tidy_dates <- mdy(random_dates)
```

From:

```
 [1] "June 05, 2018"     "December 23, 2019" "October 20, 2019"  "July 17, 2019"     "February 26, 2019" "January 25, 2018" 
 [7] "August 16, 2018"   "February 08, 2019" "July 31, 2019"     "May 05, 2019"      "November 30, 2018" "March 28, 2018"
```

To:

```
 [1] "2018-06-05" "2019-12-23" "2019-10-20" "2019-07-17" "2019-02-26" "2018-01-25" "2018-08-16" "2019-02-08" "2019-07-31" "2019-05-05"
[11] "2018-11-30" "2018-03-28"
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear that I need to extract multiple dates (about 200 or so) first. After that, I should be able to use mday() to convert the format similar to your example

Comment: Thanks! this would be an exact solution to conversion part, but I still have to figure out the right regex to only extract these dates first.

Comment: Put parentheses around the months, and don't forget to include April! `pattern <- "(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}"`

Comment: That was it! Parantheses around months. Thanks for pointing out that April was missing as well :)  What does parantheses actually do in this?

Comment: The parentheses clarify that final alternation is just `December` and belongs together with the preceding list of months, rather than December plus the day and year. Without the parentheses, the regex matches the word 'January' through to 'November' by itself, or 'December dd, yyyy'.